# Write to a local file through JNLP

Tags: java, security, file-io, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a specific requirement to read a resource from jar file and then write it to local disk. But when I try to write that resource to local disk an exception:

```
java.io.FilePermission (write) is raised.
```

I have my jar signed. I have also tried the following solution but it does not work either.

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
```

Nothing seems to work.

Am I missing a step after signing jar because this is the most common solution available everywhere?

How can I write to a local file without using policy files (because that can't be done on each client machine)?

Comment: Looked into the various services?  There is one for accessing the local filesystem if I recall correctly.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  See my comment below.  ( Try the demo. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thanks for creating JaNeLa, btw :)

Comment: @haylem  Thanks for reminding me to add:  Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JNLP also needs to specify:

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

See the [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) for details.

---

I would generally use the `FileSaveService` as detailed in Tom's answer, but this sounds more like a situation where the 'file' could be a default properties file for configuring the app.  The save service is not well suited to that, since the app. has no way to know where the file is stored, or how to access it later.  For security reasons, the `FileContents` object that is provided in place of a `File` has no methods that return the path.

In that case, extract the details of the config. file & store them using the `PersistenceService` of the JNLP API.  Here is a [demo. of the `PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).  This service is also available to sand-boxed apps. (no code signing voodoo).

Comment: security tag helped me. This is the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I was using FileSaveService and saw that you are the author of the same. While using the same I found that JNLP Client is consistently ignoring the file-name and file extension I have given in method invocation. Can you please help me with how to make JNLP Client honor these given parameters while invoking the `saveFileDialog` method. And also is there a way to know the location where user has stored the file?

Comment: Post a new question with example content of the JNLP used for your test.  Did the ZZZ file extension work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can save a file, with user interaction, from an unsigned WebStart application using [`javax.jnlp.FileSaveService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileSaveService.html).

Possibly a piece you are missing is marking the aplication as secure in the JNLP file. However, writing a secure application is a little tricky, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Note "unsigned".  This mean that it can run in the sandbox without code signing voodoo.

Comment: The dialog will have a warning icon if the application is unsigned.

Comment: @finnw IIRC, the save as dialog wont have a warning icon, as it's from the "secure" AppContext. However, I believe you still get a completely pointless warning dialog before the save as dialog.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline can in  know the path using this FileSaveService where user has stored the file.