# Log4j2 Logging on Client System through Java Webstart

Tags: java, log4j2, java-web-start

I have a JWS application that uses log4j2 locally and it writes its log files in the a "logs" directory in the root directory to a rolling log file within. This works fine when you run the application on the server but when a client pulls it through web start to their machine, the application throws an exception because it cannot find the log file when log4j is initializing. I'm guessing that through the web browser sandbox, the app is unable to create the file structure. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\SystemApp.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Did you check the path? Like Mac and windows has different path format.

Comment: Which path? Honestly I haven't even figured out where these webstart jar files are sent on the client machine to be run. But the path "logs\SystemApp.log" is a relative one. Also these are currently only on windows machines.

Comment: Try using an absolute path. Make sure the path exists on the client machine on which you are testing.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023018/write-to-a-local-file-through-jnlp) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks DB but my JNLP does already assign 'all-permissions' and is properly signed, so no dice :(

Comment: Ok I tested the full path and it does work (in the log4j config). Though since this app will be run on various computers over webstart as well as locally on certain prebuilt (controlled) machines, I really don't feel comfortable setting a hard coded path... Any other options?

Comment: @Steve11235 Absolute path works if it exists or not. Just seems relative paths do not. Not sure what to do because this app runs through normal java as well as on webstart. Not sure how to define different logging paths for diff scenarios like that.